# Directions API on Android

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2, google-directions-api

While I was going through this [blog](http://thumblines.com/2012/02/05/driving-directions-in-native-ios-and-android-apps/), I got confused about using the Directions API on android.
Is it possible to integrate the Directions API on the Map?
To make it more clear, I am working on an application that would take in inputs from the users  for things like `source` and `destinations` ... taking these inputs I would like to display an appropriate map having both the walking and driving directions depicted. Is just a `JSON parser (or XML)` enough to support this wish of mine, along with a canvas to draw on ... or will I have to create **my own API** to get this done?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes it is possible to intergrate direcitons api with map.
There is no need to write your own API. You can achieve this very easily. 
With Google android api V2 there is no need to draw canvas. Adding things in it is very easy.

Please read here for Google Maps
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start

and for directions

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/

During the process you have any specific problem then please ask that.

Thanks,

Comment: "this service is not designed to respond in real time to user input, for example" https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/

Comment: Technically you _should_ be creating your own API to proxy requests, because the API key can only be secured using IP address restrictions, which you can't do if it's the devices themselves hitting the API. Without it, someone can easily abuse your API key.